# Remove sidemenu for login page

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am currently working on an Ionic app and I understood that Ionic recently became Ionic 3. In the past, I worked with Ionic 2 and there was `app.js`.

When I created a new project and I wanted to remove sidemenu for my login page, I couldn't find the `app.js`.

Ionic 2 code

```
 app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('login', {
            url: '/login',
            controller: 'loginCtrl',
            templateUrl: 'login.html'
});

app.controller('loginCtrl', function($scope, $state,$ionicSideMenuDelegate) {
    $ionicSideMenuDelegate.canDragContent(false);
});
```

May I know how does this work now in the new Ionic?

Comment: the code you shared is based on ionic 1 not ionic 2 create a project using ionic cli the command to create ionic 3 sidemenu project is **ionic start myApp sidemenu**  pls refer the [doc](https://ionicframework.com/getting-started)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way, In your login page:

**LoginPage.ts**

```
import {MenuController} from 'ionic-angular';

export class LoginPage {

constructor(private menu : MenuController){}

ionViewDidEnter()
  {
    // Disable the root left menu when entering this page
    this.menu.enable(false);
  }

ionViewWillLeave()
 {
      // enable the root left menu when leaving this page
      this.menu.enable(true);
 }
   }
```